# Django view with slug and id

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have this URL

```
    path('kategorie/<slug:slug>-<int:pk>', views.category_view, name="category_view"),
```

And this view

```
def category_view(request,slug,pk):
    categories = EcommerceProductCategory.objects.all().filter(slug=slug, pk=pk).order_by('-created_at')

    product = Product.objects.filter(slug=slug).order_by('-created_at')

    context = {
        'categories': categories,
        'product': product,
    }
    return render(request, 'ecommerce/category_view.html', context=context)
```

Now i wanna show on that page category_view.html only the products that have particular slug and pk. Lets say kategorie/cat-4.
Cat is the category.slug
and the category.pk is 4
and i only wanna show the products that have this category and this pk.
(Btw yes product is connected with Ecommerce via M2M)

Comment: And what's wrong then? What is your issue?

Comment: The code doesnt work and i dont know how to make it work

Comment: Please describe the expected behavior as well as any errors or unexpected behaviors you are observing. Simply saying "it doesn't work" doesn't help us understand the problem. As it is currently written, your question doesn't state a problem and does not ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You can send pk as last character of slug separated by `-` from frontend and change url pattern to:

```
path('kategorie/<slug:slug>/', views.category_view, name="category_view"),
```

Secondly in your view you extract slug and pk like this:

```
def category_view(request, slug):
   pk = slug.split('-')[-1]
   slug = slug[:-len("-" + pk)]
   product = Product.objects.filter(id=pk, slug=slug).order_by('-created_at')
```

Lastly if you don't need category why are you using it ? And remove that `all()` i think that unnecessary like this:

```
categories = EcommerceProductCategory.objects.filter(slug=slug, pk=pk).order_by('-created_at')
```

Comment: Yes but i don't want the <slug:slug>/<int:pk> i want it after a "-" sign because a category needs to match a slug-name but some categories have the same name but they have different parents in categories tree, so the id is needed to distinguish them.

Comment: Updated the answer check

Comment: @jakubstrawa if the answer fixed your issue you can mark it as accepted.